# How to set shadow outline (solid) around UILabel text in Swift?

Tags: swift, uilabel

I want to set shadow outline (solid) around UILabel text.

I tried below code: -

```
class BottomToolBarLabel: UILabel {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    }
}
```

But this is not working as I required. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

I required output like: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code :-

```
class BottomToolBarLabel : UILabel{
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {



    let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        c!.setLineWidth(10);
        c!.setLineJoin(.round);

        c!.setTextDrawingMode(.stroke);
    self.textColor = UIColor.white
    super.drawText(in: rect)

        c!.setTextDrawingMode(.fill);
    self.textColor = UIColor.black
    self.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 0)
   super.drawText(in: rect)


    }
}
```